# Weird crash when pressing a button

Tags: ios, swift

I set up a button that when it's pressed, it's supposed to change it's icon and mute the mic, but I get this error and the app crashes.

```
Thread 1: EXC_BREAKPOINT (code=1, subcode=0x1eb5bbb2c)
```

Here is the code:

```
@IBAction func btnMuteMicPressed(_ sender: Any) {
    publisher.publishAudio = !publisher.publishAudio

    let buttonImage: UIImage  = {
        if !publisher.publishAudio {
            return #imageLiteral(resourceName: "group3-1")
        } else {
            return #imageLiteral(resourceName: "group3")

        }
    }()

    btnMuteMic.setImage(buttonImage, for: .normal)
}
```

It crashes on the first return. Why?

Comment: I advice you to use an exception breakpoint http://blog.manbolo.com/2012/01/23/xcode-tips-1-break-on-exceptions

Comment: Did you try to simplifying your code (remove the closure) and can you assure that both image resources are available?

Comment: You mean the `buttonImage` closure? How would you simplify it? Yes, both resources are available. It lets me select the images.

Comment: Is that ***all*** the code in that function, or have you left something out? Is `publisher` an instance of a class? Does that class do something else when the value of `.publishAudio` is set?

Comment: Yes, that's all the code in the function. Yes, `publisher` is an instance of a class. No, it just stops sending audio.

Comment: Why use a local closure at all?

Comment: I don't know. How would you rewrite it? Is there a better way?

Comment: A quick test of your `btnMuteMicPressed` func works fine for me (I created a simple `Publisher` class with just the one `.publishAudio` bool var. *"...it just stops sending audio..."* makes me suspect the error is happening there, ***not*** in setting the button image.

Comment: Are you 100% sure that both images are correct?  Have you tried just manually setting it to one image and then the other (i.e. remove the if statement)?  I've had it let me set it to something like "image1" in the code only to have it crash as it should gave been "Image1"

Comment: @DonMag I commented out the `buttonImage` part and it works fine, so I don't think the problem is with `publisher`

Comment: @vukurigusi - Either try it with a simple bool var, or, in your `Publisher` class, comment out whatever code runs to stop / start the audio. As I said, your code worked fine for me (without the Publisher class doing anything else).